# library to warp text on HTML5 canvas similar to csswarp on DOM

Tags: canvas, warp

I want to warp text on HTML Canvas around Bezeir curves and Circles. CSSWarp library does that using CSS3 on DOM. I am looking for a library which does the same on HTML canvas. I googled in vain. Did anyone come across such a library? Or was anyone able to successfully warp text on HTML5 canvas around bezeir curves/circles?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if something similar has been done in HTML5, but there are a tons of experiments done in Flash. Yous should check this blog: http://algorithmist.wordpress.com/. It's completely dedicated to bazier spline exploration. Another great resource is this site: http://www.tinaja.com/cubic01.shtml with tons of examples and great articles related to the subject. Here is paper which explain the concept behind wrapping text to a bazier spline: http://www.tinaja.com/glib/nonlingr.pdf

And as a side note i can nominate two great and complex library which does the desired effect only on SVG: [3d](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) and [PaperJS](http://paperjs.org/examples/).