# Is there anyway to warp/mesh text in an HTML5 canvas element?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to be able to dynamically warp the text generated within an HTML5 canvas element.

The effect I wish to achieve is similar to this image...

[image]

The blue lines are a representation of the transformation.

I understand that I can use matrix transformations on text but cannot seem to get my head around them.

How would I go about warping text in this manner?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using the matrix transformations on text.  Although it appears to be the only possible way I simply cannot get my head around the coordinates system and how the above visual representation would be achieved within a transformation matrix.

Comment: Maybe this will help to get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311928/library-to-warp-text-on-html5-canvas-similar-to-csswarp-on-dom

Comment: @esimov - Thanks, very useful info... I think the difficulty arises from the fact that I only want to warp part of the text rather than run the whole lot along a path.  This appears to be trickier than I originally imagined.  Regardless, very helpful. cheers.